# undefined method `new' for Paperclip:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I encounter error **undefined method `new' for Paperclip:Module**
while running rake db:migrate to update table for PaperClip.

Herewith in migration class

```
class ForPaperclip < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :photos do |t|
      t.has_attached_file :shot
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :photos, :shot
  end
end
```

I am using paperclip 2.6.0, ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.1.0
Any idea?

Below is the error stack.

```
/Users/Sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:517:in `load_migration'

/Users/Sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:512:in `migration'

/Users/Sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:509:in `rescue in migrate'

/Users/Sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:507:in `migrate'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, this is really my bad. I created the migration file called *_paperclip.txt thus rails is unnecessarily looking for Paperclip module. It works fine, after I rename the migration file